# Define an $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ function that is

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Hi I'm preparing for an exam and was going through exercises on functions. I stumbled upon this question and didn't know how to answer it.

Give an $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ function that
is one-to-one but not onto,

Answer:  $f(n)=n+1$

onto but not one-to-one,

Answer: $F(n) =\begin{cases} n-1 &\mbox{if } n > 0 \\ 0 & \mbox{if } n= 0\end{cases}$

both one-to-one and onto (but different from $\text{id}_{\mathbb{N}}$),

Answer: $F(n) =\begin{cases} n-1 &\mbox{if } n\text{ is odd}\\ n+1 &\mbox{if }n\text{ is even}\end{cases}$

neither one-to-one nor onto.

Answer: $F(n) = 42$

When I looked at the answers to try & understand I couldn't figure out why they were correct. Why was 42 chosen as a neither one-to-one or onto function (based on what equation)? And how does $n-1$ or $n+1$ define the domain & codomain which then can determine the type of the function?

Thank you very much!

Comment: 42 was chosen because it's a reference to "A Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy". I don't understand the rest of your question though.

Comment: Do you understand the definition of one to one and onto?

Comment: The "42" could've been any number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll remark on two of your four problems, and hopefully that will be enough to get you going on the others. First, you have already been given the domain and codomain for your function $f$, namely $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$. Thus, for *every* one of of your problems you are considering the mapping $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by ___ ; that is, your domain and codomain are the same for all of your problems but only the definition of the mapping changes (what is being mapped to what, specifically).

**One-to-one but not onto:** Here, $f(n)=n+1$ works because $n_1+1=n_2+1\Leftrightarrow n_1=n_2$ (which means $f$ is one-to-one), but is $0\in\mathbb{N}$ ever mapped to? No; thus, $f$ is not onto.

**Neither one-to-one nor onto:** Here, $f(n)=42$. Well, $f(7)=42=f(8)$ but $7\neq8$; thus, $f$ is not one-to-one. Also, is $0\in\mathbb{N}$ ever mapped to? For that matter, is anything other than $42$ ever mapped to? No. Thus, $f$ is not onto either.

Can you see how to apply that reasoning to your other problems?

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to figure out the other two too!

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful! If this *answered* your question, then it is seen as good practice to accept the answer (of course, do not accept it unless it really helped and/or answered your question). I am telling you this since you are rather new to the site--accepting an answer is often seen as accomplishing two things: 1) It gives the answerer due credit/acknowledgment, and 2) it lets the MSE community know that you are satisfied with the answer(s) you received. For example, you can look at my own questions--one's that do not have accepted answers I still consider open. `:-)`

Comment: You may also find [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) about the increased privileges you receive as your reputation increases. Also, to ensure a positive experience on the site, definitely read closely over [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Everyone on here is pretty sensitive when someone pitches a question that is not properly formatted (generally it is perceived as being lazy). It makes everything more readable. Finally, showing your own work and thoughts...crucial. MSE can be awesome then!